# Vertically centered page "jumping" in Chrome on reload, FF and IE working fine

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I use the following jQuery code to vertically center a website inside the browser window, if it is higher than the outer wrapper-div (which has a fixed width and height).

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

     centerPage();
)};

// center page vertically if viewport higher than wrapper
function centerPage(){  

   var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
   var siteHeight = $('#wrapper').height();

   if(viewportHeight > siteHeight){

         $('#wrapper').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : -$('#wrapper').outerWidth()/2,
        'margin-top' : -$('#wrapper').outerHeight()/2
      });
   }


}
```

This works just fine in Firefox and Internet Explorer 11; here the website always stays fixed in the centered position.

But in Chrome, everytime the page is reloaded, e.g. by navigating through the menu, the wrapper jumps to the top and then back to center. Or rather it is rendered before the js changes are applied...like the code is running too late in Chrome.

I'm quite new to JS so I had difficulties understanding what I found about Chrome loading things too late, but it seems to be a common problem.

Is this a Chrome issue due to its way of handling JS files or is there any workaround to make the javascript load faster or earlier in Chrome in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only assume what you are trying to achieve is for your webpage to be centrally aligned at all times. This can be done solely using CSS without any need for JS. Simply set a fixed width on the wrapping element and set `margin` to `auto` or `0 auto`. This should then center the page for you.

**EDIT**

On the subject of vertical positioning, i'd create a fixed height viewport and use `position: absolute` and `margin: auto` to position it. I have created a fiddle to demonstrate how this can be done. This would of course require a parent element set with `position: relative` and also believe that element would too require a fixed height, but this is better than using a JavaScript solution.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8jL8b8L/1/

**EDIT 2**

Two more fiddles to demonstrate how you can use the `html` and `body` elements to achieve the desired results. By setting both of these elements to `height: 100%` and `width: 100%` then using `position: relative` on the `body` you can then use `bottom: 0; height: 90%; left: 0; margin: auto; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0;` on the `viewport/wrapper` element you create in order to center it veritcally.

http://jsfiddle.net/h8jL8b8L/2/

http://jsfiddle.net/h8jL8b8L/3/

Comment: As far as I know, margin 0 auto only centers horizontally, but not vertically. And I specifically need it to be vertically centered.

Comment: Oh i see vertical centering. Do you have a fixed viewport in terms of height of the page? Or is the height of the viewport variable?

Comment: The height of the page is fixed but the viewport can be variable. That's why the top margin should be calculated everytime the page is loaded.

Comment: @eve i've added a little more context above with a possible solution to your problem. It's a workaround at best but saves you having to use JavaScript and you can potentially do some clever things with `position: absolute` and auto-margins.

Comment: Tanks for the fiddle. It's a nice way to center div inside div actually, so I will keep it in mind (need this more often than I expected ;) ). 
But I don't know how this could be applied in my case. With "variable viewport" I mean the browser window or the monitor screen. Since I never know what size someones screen is, I need to get the viewport height with JavaScript and adapt the margin to it. I don't see how a CSS only solution could work in this case.

Comment: Hang on, ill update the fiddle and repost. I think there may be a way round this.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h8jL8b8L/2/ Check that out, if you set the `<html>` `height` and `width` to `100%`, then set the `body` to `height: 100%; position: relative; width: 100%;` this should then allow you to center your viewport at whatever height you want the `inner-box` to be. So it could be `10px` high or `100%` high.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/h8jL8b8L/3/ Another fiddle to demonstrate the point i made above. Hope this helps :)

Comment: Sorry for answering so late!  The first of the new fiddles works like a charm! Thank you so much =) Its exactly what I wanted to achieve. The hiding option with js was still a bit jumpy and this way I avoid the no-script issue ;)

Comment: @eve no problem, glad i could be of assistance! :)

Answer (score 1):

What if you hid it until after your centerPage() function runs? Like this...

js:

```
// center page vertically if viewport higher than wrapper
function centerPage(){  

   var viewportHeight = $(window).height();
   var siteHeight = $('#wrapper').height();

   if(viewportHeight > siteHeight){
         $('#wrapper').css({
        'position' : 'absolute',
        'left' : '50%',
        'top' : '50%',
        'margin-left' : -$('#wrapper').outerWidth()/2,
        'margin-top' : -$('#wrapper').outerHeight()/2,
        'display' : 'block'
      });
   }
}
$(function(){
    centerPage();
});
```

html:

```
<div id="wrapper" style="display:none;">center</div>
```

jsfiddle demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/a21wrepv/

Comment: Thanks, yes I thought about this too. But that would mean that the page is not visible at all if somebody has javascript deactivated or not?

Comment: That is a good point, maybe you could get around it like this... http://jsfiddle.net/a21wrepv/1/

Comment: In the fiddle above, the html in the <noscript> tags would be rendered if the client did not have js, otherwise the js would run and append your wrapper to the DOM then center it.

Comment: Ah right, I forgot that that noscript thing existed ;). I will try this and tell how it works. Thanks!

Comment: I tried this option now and it works and is not (that) jumpy anymore (there is still a little delay visible), but I could not get the <noscript> to work. When I deactivated Javascript in the browser it did not apply the css rule to make the hidden div visible again. I did use the css only option from the first answer now which works for me. But thanks for your advice